# How to make a polygon and point shapefile line up to do a spatial join?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, overlay, spatial-join

I have a polygon with a North_America_Lambert_Conformal_Conic coordinate system and a point shapefile which had a WGS 1984(DD) coordinate system.

I defined projection and projected both of them to North_America_Lambert_Conformal_Conic coordinate system. The two shapefiles do not overlay. If checked in the screen shot of ArcGIS 10.2, only one of the layer appears (whichever I have zoomed to).

Can someone please guide me on how I can get this to shapes to line up or overlay?

My intention is to do a spatial join on them so that I can count some point features within the polygons.

Comment: You say your original polygon and point shapefiles had different coordinate systems.  That should not be a problem for a Spatial Join, because if both of the original shapefiles have their coordinate systems set correctly, ArcMap should correctly project them "on the fly" so that they overlay correctly.  **Were they overlaying correctly before you projected them both into the same coordinate system?**

Comment: It sounds like maybe you defined them while they already had a definition.  Don't confuse defining with projecting.  The reason I'm questioning this is because you mention the two coordinate systems they are in but then go on to say that you defined and projected them.  If you defined them both to be North_American_Lambert_Conformal_Conic before projecting, the one that was in WGS 1984 is going to be all out of whack.  Hope I'm being clear.  Bottom line is...  If the data is already shown as being anything other than <undefined>,  you don't need to use the define tool at all.  Just project.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly! So, I just did the spatial join and went right ahead with the count without the need to make sure they were overlaying. Thank you!